# Does google penalize the person that registered the domain name for getting site deranked?

Tags: penalty

All my sites got hit by Penguin in mid 2000's, nothing too bad, just moving company sites with article directory links, exact anchor text etc...got hit by negative SEO also

If I buy new domain names, with same registrar, will google transfer the bad karma from my name?

Would registering the domain name privately protect me?

Let's say some guy is a total spammer, like really, really, really bad, he builds like 1000 sex websites, all registered in his name and spams in the millions!

What will google think of him? Is he on their radar forever?

Comment: Don't have anything solid to back this one up. How about just using a different email for registry or just use the company name for Reg?

Comment: If you register a new domain using privacy, how would they possibly associate that with you? Are you planning on providing the same content or doing the same activities that resulted in the penalties? If so, that would seem like a futile exercise.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but why are you insinuating I'll be doing this again? Obviously I wouldn't be asking this question if that was my intention? ;) The activities I did that got me penalized were mainstream in the early 2000's , article marketing, exact match anchor text etc...all 100% honest and white hat in those days, penalized site is a moving company with 24 years on BBB, with perfect track record, domain name is 18 years old. Last thing I want to do is spam!

Comment: It's a fair question based on what you stated: `Would registering the domain name privately protect me?`. Why would you need "protection" if you're not planning on doing the same thing(s)? I didn't mention "spam" either, however you did twice... The simple answer here is domains are treated independently in terms of penalties, so if you're not planning on doing the same thing(s), then there's no need to worry about being penalized again.

Comment: This question is really too [opinion-based](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) since we do not know the internal workings of Google's algorithms, or what you'd be providing/pursuing, so this cannot be answered definitively.

Comment: Thanks Dan, yes, it makes sense. I guess I'll register privately and cross my fingers, I guess I'm just being paranoid for nothing, actually the site in question still ranks, but now for the penalized keywords. I'm sure I'll be fine ;) Time to buy a new domain and start over!